# How do I solve this path error when trying to run ANSYS with parallel processing using MPI?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, path, mpi, system-variable

I am currently attempting to write a batch file that will open ANSYS Autodyn using MPI on a virtual machine. Whenever I attempt to start the program however, I get the following message;

> WARNING: No cached password or password provided.
>            use '-pass' or '-cache' to provide password
>
> AVS/Express Developer Edition
>       Version: 8.0 fcs pc10_64
>       Project: C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN
>
> --- Error detected in: module: OMopen_file ---
>   can't find file with name: appl and suffix: v or vo in path: C:\Program
>   Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN\v;C:\Program Files\ANSYS
>   Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN;.
>   MPI Application rank 0 exited before MPI_Init() with status -1

The problem is caused by the fact that the path specified in the last paragraph there should be;

> C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN\winx64

The problem is that I cannot find the variable that specifies that path, and so I cannot change it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or am I stuck using just one core for the time being?

The batch file code is;

```
set MPI_ROOT=C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\commonfiles\MPI\Platform\9.1.2.1\winx64
"%MPI_ROOT%\bin\mpirun.exe" -mpi64 -prot -e MPI_WORKDIR="C:\Users\umjonesa\AppData\Roaming\Ansys\v162\AUTODYN" -f applfile.txt
PAUSE
```

That opens the .txt called applfile;

> -e MPI_FLAGS=y0 -h localhost -np 1 "C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN\winx64\autodyn.exe"
>   -h localhost -np 3 "C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v162\aisol\AUTODYN\winx64\adslave.exe"

which should open an autodyn window with one master and three slaves.

Comment: You need to provide the code you have so far that starts the ANSYS Autodyn program.

Comment: @ Dennis van Gils Edited, thank you